# WIX 4.0 - how to make a minor Upgrade build

Tags: wix4

I've been reading about WIX4, but don't quite understand what I need to do with my installation to make it upgradable and not put multiple versions into Control Panel 'Program and Features'.  Currently in my Product.wxs, I have the following:

```
<Package Name="$(var.Name)" Language="1033" Version="$(var.Version)" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeGUID)" InstallerVersion="300">
```

And, of course in my settings file (config.wxi) I have all of these variable settings.

Now- I know this is not enough.  From using Installshield, I recall not being able to touch the Upgrade GUID.  Usually with Installshield, I changed the Product GUID and it would allow me to upgrader properly. I'm not grasping the concept with WIX4, though :(

Answer (score 0):

You want a [MajorUpgrade element](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/schema/wxs/majorupgrade/), like:

```xml
<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.DowngradeError)" />
```

Comment: I have something like that already:
<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />

That only does anything if I keep the same product GUID, though.  Which, I won't because if I don't have that GUID in the Package tag - it will create a new one each time.

Comment: Major upgrades need a stable upgrade code and a changing product code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/major-upgrades

Comment: I have a stable upgrade code and changing product code, though.  And I still get multiple versions showing up in Control Panel when I install a new version.

Comment: You need some verbose logs for debugging.

Comment: Found out it was my stupid build number.  I had something like xx.xx.xx.xx where the last 2 were updates within a given day.  I noticed when I did a build on the next day, it replaced all the others.  So - essentially it was my non-comprehension of versioning that caused this problem.